# Encoding a line break for Twilio SMS using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, twilio

I'm using WebApi 2.2 to ramp up on the Twilio API.  I have the Twilio C# libraries installed.

I'm using a form to capture a string in my web app, and I send that down to webAPI.  I'm wondering how I can leverage the C# libraries to send a message with line breaks.

The example code shows the following:

```
        var msg = twilio.SendMessage("+15084043345", "+15084043345", "Can you believe it's this easy to send an SMS?!");
```

However, I'm not sure how to include a line break in this message.  Should I be inserting anything into this string clientside to represent a linebreak?  Any guidance would be awesome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twilio Evangelist here.

This is actually super simple:

```
var msg = twilio.SendMessage("+15084043345", "+15084043345", "Hello.\nCan you believe it's this easy to send an SMS?!");
```

Will result in:

`Hello.
Can you believe it's this easy to send an SMS?!`

Just like printing strings to the console, `\n`, `\r\n`, and `\r` can be used to insert a new line. I can't say definitively what is best to use across all handsets, but I have found `\n` to be pretty reliable. (I can say all three of these work on my iOS 8 device perfectly...)

Comment: Does `\n` count as two characters?  Asked another way - if I want my user's message to fit in a single text, should them adding a break give them only 158 characters to work with?

Comment: This an excellent question. It's actually 2 characters, because SMS uses GSM 03.38 encoding... You can read more about that here: https://www.twilio.com/engineering/2012/11/08/adventures-in-unicode-sms

Comment: Awesome.  If you get a moment, I've just posted a question of my own: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219969/twilio-test-credentials-waitingforactivation-when-i-try-to-purchase-a-number

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show new line in sms like

Account Name : suraj

Age : 24

then here is a code for asp.net VB

Dim value As String = "Account Name :" & "suraj" & vbCrLf & "Age :" & " 24"

it will show new line in SMS not in web page