# Twilio Test Credentials: WaitingForActivation when I try to purchase a number?

Tags: c#, twilio

I have the following code:

```
    public void PurchaseNumber(string username, string phoneNumber) {

        var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(accountSid, authToken);

        var options = new PhoneNumberOptions {
            VoiceUrl = "",
            PhoneNumber = "+15005550006"
        };
        var number = twilio.AddIncomingPhoneNumber(options);

        Console.WriteLine(number.Id); // Sid is not available

        return;
    }
```

Two issues - `number.Sid` is not available, as the samples display, and `number.Status` always shows "WaitingForActivation".  What am I doing wrong?

Update: This also happens with the 'unavailable' number, not just with the 'valid and available' one.  Is the usage of magic numbers available to trial accounts?  I *am* using the SID and Token from the `https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/test-credentials` page.

This also happens if I change one of the characters of my SID - so it seems that my SID is invalid, despite grabbing it directly off of my `/developer-tools` page.

**Final Update** - it was because I was using the PreRelease version of the Twilio nuget package.  I uninstalled it and installed the non-prerelease version and `Sid` became available and everything started working.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you have everything working?

Comment: Hmmm, thats very interesting.  Would you mind filing an issue on the github page for this.  Sounds like I should look at the pre-release version and see if there is a bug in it.

github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp 

If you would, mark the issue with the Alpha label so I know its specific to the pre-release version.

Comment: @DevinRader - thanks for the help on the other question Devin.  Just created an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Final Update - it was because I was using the PreRelease version of the Twilio nuget package. I uninstalled it and installed the non-prerelease version and Sid became available and everything started working.